# Is the generic deformation of a symplectic variety affine?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, holomorphic-symplectic, deformation-theory

Kaledin and Verbitsky have shown that symplectic varities have a remarkably nice deformation theory *as symplectic varieties.*

Let $X$ be a symplectic variety (a smooth quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ equipped with a nondegenerate closed algebraic 2-form $\Omega$); then there is a universal formal deformation $\tilde X$ over $H^2(X;\mathbb{C})$ completed at the class $[\Omega]$.

In many examples, it seems that this deformation is generically affine; that is, its fiber at the generic point is an affine scheme.  For example, $T^*G/B$ deforms to a generic coadjoint orbit in $\mathfrak{g}^*$, and if $X$ is a hyperkähler quotient, like a quiver variety, then the deformation comes from varying the complex moment map, and the deformation is also generically affine (since a GIT quotient by a free action of a reductive group is always affine).

Of course, I don't think this always happens; the product of two elliptic curves is symplectic, but doing this deformation should just change the $j$-functions of the curves simultaneously.  So, clearly one needs some kind of extra condition.  I've opted for "resolution of singularities of its affinization."

So my question is:

> Let $X$ be a symplectic variety which is a resolution of singularities of its affinization.  Is $\tilde X$ generically affine?

**EDIT:** As was pointed out in Misha Verbitksy's answer below, the deformation is not canonically algebraic.  I believe though that if you assume that $X$ has a $\mathbb{C}^*$-action which is dilating (Definition 1.7 of  [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608143.pdf)), then $\tilde X$ will also have a $\mathbb{C}^*$-action which acts by dilation on $H^2(X;\mathbb{C})$ and there will be a unique algebraic structure for which weight vectors of the $\mathbb{C}^*$-action are algebraic functions.  It is this algebraic structure I want.

**EDIT:** Since it's buried a little bit in comments, let me just put here that it's true and proven by Kaledin in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312134).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being "affine" in this case  does not make much sense,
because the hyperkaehler deformation is a complex manifold, without 
a fixed algebraic structure. Simpson produced an example of a 
hyperkaehler deformation of a space of flat bundles 
admitting several algebraic structures, both
inducing the same Stein complex structure; one of them 
is affine, another has no global algebraic functions.
In fact, the space F of flat line bundles on elliptic curve 
(with an appropriate algebraic structure, defined by 
Simpson) is an example of such a  manifold,
it is biholomorphic to $C^*\times C^*$, but 
this biholomorphic equivalence is not algebraic,
and F has no global algebraic functions.

However, you can show that a hyperkaehler deformation
of a resolution of something affine has  no non-trivial complex
subvarieties (arXiv:math/0312520), except, possibly, some 
hyperkaehler  subvarieties The latter don't exist, because 
the holomorphic symplectic form $\Omega$ on such a manifold
is is lifted from the base, which is affine, hence $\Omega$
vanishes on all complex subvarieties.

Therefore, a typical fiber of such a deformation is Stein.

Indeed, a hyperkaehler deformation  of a 
resolution of something affine remains holomorphically convex. To see this
if you produce a function which is strictly plurisubharmonic outside of
a compact set (we have such a function, because we started from something 
affine), and apply the Remmert reduction.

Comment: That's a very useful answer.  Thanks a lot.  

Comment: Though, I suppose it's worth asking: in the situations I'm interested in, the variety $X$ has a $\mathbb{C}^*$-action which is dilating on the affinization (as defined in http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608143.pdf), and thus I can try to put an algebraic structure $\tilde X$ by making weight vectors algebraic.  Do you know if that will give the deformation an algebraic structure for which it is generically affine?

Comment: In this case, it is affine, but I don't know a precise reference. I think it is due to Kaledin.
I am surprised it's not stated in the paper you cited.

For an easy proof, notice that your C^*-action gives a
C^*-action with positive weights on a deformation of your original (singular)
affine manifold. Therefore the total space of its deformation (which has
the same generic fibers as the hyperkaehler deformation of its blow-up)
is affine, hence its fibers are affine, too.

Comment: It's not stated explicitly in the paper I referenced, but I see now that it is clear from the existence and properties of the twistor deformation.